# Node.Js Exception Handling

Tags: node.js

In the following code I'm able to catch the exception and print it but for some reason my program breaks there and it makes me to restart the application. Can't I handle it gracefully with out restarting it?

```
var checkRecordId = function (recordId)
{

        if (recordId < 0)
            throw new Error ("Record Id can not be 0 or less");

}


var getReport = function (dateRange , recordId)
{

        try
        {
            checkRecordId (recordId);
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            console.log (err);
        }   
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to call the function? Also the error text and stack trace

Comment: @Siva, you have asked asked 8 questions and accepted no answers on those questions. You should really fix that, otherwise nobody will be willing to help you.

Comment: @d11wtq, I really dont know that there is something that I have accept. Truth is I have got answer for all the queries that I posted so far. Could you please tell me how to accept the answer? Should I have to click the tick mark right below to voting mark?

Comment: @Siva, yes, click the tick on the answer you want to accept ;)

Comment: All good, it's not always clear to new users ;) Are you able to post the backtrace in relation to this specific question? I can't see any reason why it should crash, so I think it's something else.

Comment: @d11wtq, I have fixed it. Thought I handled the exception, I made a mistake inside the calling method. I had gone through the trace message and found that I didnt configure the Log4JS (Logging mechanism) properly. Thank you !!